# Android - BLE Advertising Hardware specific issues

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

I wanted to check if any of you guys had experience with working with BLE advertising and the constraints that you have found with the framework and hardware. I have been following this tutorial to turn an Android device into a beacon https://www.pubnub.com/blog/2015-04-16-build-android-ibeacon-beacon-emitter/ and have found some issues while broadcasting packets, depending on the device manufacturer.

Broadcasting manufacturer data with https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/le/AdvertiseData.Builder.html

> addManufacturerData()

we are able to broadcast multiple packets as we desire with Samsung devices. However, other manufacturers (HTC, Motorola) have issues with quick consecutive broadcasts, resulting in delays in broadcasts or packets dropped. When setting the advertise timeout to 250ms, only Samsung devices are able to quickly broadcast packets. In order for other devices to work as expected, we have to limit the timeout to 1 sec in order to get most packets broadcasted.

We have tested with Samsung Galaxy phones (S6/S7/S8) and they all perform well despite the different Bluetooth (4.1/5) and Android (5,6,7) versions.

Have any of you guys experienced similar issues?

Comment: Related (but older) document on what one firm found about Android BLE: https://atmosphere.anaren.com/wiki/Android_Issues_With_Bluetooth_Low_Energy

Comment: Thank you for the information. This definitely provides a good starting point to understand the limitation of certain chips.

Comment: link doesn't work anymore